# ng2-charts, ocultar data en linea de puntos line chart

Tags: angular, canvas, charts, angular10, chart.js

Estoy usando ng2-charts, tengo este problema de que se muestra el valor de la data en la linea de puntos, como lo podria ocultar o quitar?

Tengo definido los colores, las opciones, la data y los labels, pero en la zona de puntos, se muestran los colores en los puntos, pero encima el valor de la data.

[image: colores]

[image: angular]

[image: Canva HTML]

[image: canva muestra]

Comment: Por favor no compartas código por medio de imágenes, edita tu pregunta y añade tu código con el formato correcto. [¿Porqué?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/153371)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puede que tengas que configurar el lineChartPlugin con:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        display: false,
    },
}
```

Markup

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [colors]="lineChartColors"
            [legend]="lineChartLegend"
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
            [plugins]="lineChartPlugins"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Typescript

```
public lineChartLegend = true;
public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';
public lineChartPlugins = [pluginAnnotations];
```

Comment: Por favor no compartas código por medio de imágenes, edita tu respuesta y añade tu código con el formato correcto. [¿Porqué?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/153371)